# How to change color / styles in tabs-component in Vaadin-application

Tags: vaadin

In my Vaadin application (Vaadin 23.2.0) I use tabs to group my content. The main colours of my application are white, grey and some accents in red. Accordingly, I would like to style my selected tabs in red.

I have already managed the following:

- Unselected tabs are displayed in black.
- Selected tabs are displayed in red.

Now Vaadin has a transition between clicking on the tab and the selection of the tab. By default, this transition is kept in Vaadin blue, which of course does not fit my theme. And I can't manage to style this transition. I would like to either style it dark red (to make the transition from dark red to my already used lighter red #DE323C) or omit it completely.

How does this work in Vaadin?

For styling the tabs I have used the following CSS snippets so far:

```
vaadin-tab[selected] { 
    colour: #DE323C;
}

vaadin-tab[selected]::before, vaadin-tab[selected]::after { 
    background-color: #DE323C;
}
```

I did some more tests with ::before and ::after, but Vaadin is very unimpressed.

Here is a simplified version of my Java code:

```
package ch.abacus.apihub.views.list;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Paragraph;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tab;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.TabsVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;


@PageTitle("Test")
@Route(value = "test", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class TestView extends Div {
    private final Tab tab1;
    private final Tab tab2;
    private final Tab tab3;
    private final VerticalLayout content;

    public TestView() {
        // Create Tabs
        tab1 = new Tab("This is tab 1");
        tab2 = new Tab("This is tab 2");
        tab3 = new Tab("This is tab 3");

        // Event-Listener for clicking tabs
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(tab1, tab2, tab3);
        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event ->
                setContent(event.getSelectedTab())
        );

        // Tabs use available space
        tabs.addThemeVariants(TabsVariant.LUMO_EQUAL_WIDTH_TABS);

        // Create VerticalLayout for Tabs
        content = new VerticalLayout();
        content.setSpacing(false);
        setContent(tabs.getSelectedTab());

        // Add Tabs to created VerticalLayout
        add(tabs, content);
    }

    private void setContent(Tab tab) {
        content.removeAll();

        if (tab.equals(tab1)) {
            Paragraph tab1Paragraph = new Paragraph("Test tab 1");
            content.add(tab1Paragraph);

        } else if (tab.equals(tab2)) {
            Paragraph tab2Paragraph = new Paragraph("Test tab 2");
            content.add(tab2Paragraph);

        } else if (tab.equals(tab3)) {
            Paragraph tab3Paragraph = new Paragraph("Test tab 3");
            content.add(tab3Paragraph);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One minor typo in your CSS: `colour` should be `color`. Otherwise the CSS looks like it should work as expected. Where did you place the CSS?

Comment: Just tested it myself, and it works just fine as long as colour->color typo is fixed. If styles are placed in styles.css, that should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file called vaadin-tab.css in frontend/themes//components

Inside that you can style all styles of a component

For example:

```
:host {
    color: var(--lumo-primary-text-color);

    font-weight: 400;
}

:host([selected]) {
    color: black;
    background-color: var(--tosca-selection-nonfocus);
    transition: 0.6s color;
}

:host([selected].focused) {
    color: black;
    background-color: #8fc8d5;
    transition: 0.6s color;
}

:host([selected])::before, :host([selected])::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Learn more about styling components:
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/custom-theme/styling-components

Comment: It’s not absolutely necessary to place the styles in that file, and therefore inside the shadow DOM if `<vaadin-tab>`. The CSS in the original post/question look okay to me, apart from one minor typo.

Comment: You are right @jouni. But IMO it's better to keep things together.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "keeping things together". You can still place any related (i.e. for one component) CSS in a separate file, and import that into the main style sheet.

Comment: I mean that it's clear to which component the style belongs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers.

The typo only crept in on Stackoverflow. It is not present in my CSS.

I placed the CSS code in the styles.css file.

I have now created a separate style sheet for the tabs. It probably wouldn't have been necessary, but I find it quite good that all the style things for the tabs can then be found in one place.

I was able to solve the problem by copying the default styles of the tabs from the #shadow-root of the tabs and overwriting them. My vaadin-tab.css now looks like this:

```css
:host { /* Styling tab not focused etc. */
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
      font-size : 16px;
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: 500;
      opacity: 1;
      color: #282828;
      transition: 0.15s color, 0.2s transform;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      transform-origin: 50% 100%;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      overflow: hidden;
      min-width: var(--lumo-size-m);
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      text-transform : UPPERCASE;
      letter-spacing : 1px;
}

:host(:hover), :host([focus-ring]) { /* Styling tab hovered */
  color: #B11D24; /* darker red */
}

:host([selected]) { /* Styling tab selected */
  color: #DE323C;
  transition: 0.6s color;
}

:host([active]:not([selected])) { /* relevant for transition */
  color: #DE323C;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
}

:host::before, :host::after { /* Styling color line below text of tab */
  content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: var(--_lumo-tab-marker-display, block);
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      width: var(--lumo-size-s);
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #282828;
      border-radius: var(--lumo-border-radius-s) var(--lumo-border-radius-s) 0 0;
      transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0);
      transform-origin: 50% 100%;
      transition: 0.14s transform cubic-bezier(0.12, 0.32, 0.54, 1);
      will-change: transform;
}

:host([selected])::before, :host([selected])::after { /* Styling color line below text of tab selected */
  background-color: #DE323C;
}
```

Probably some CSS configurations could be removed, but I am quite satisfied: When hovering over it, the tabs are displayed in dark red and when clicking on a tab, the transition to my lighter red takes place. The Vaadin blue has now completely disappeared.